# Unable to find the instance while installing AdventureWorks2008R2_SR1

Tags: sql-server-2008, adventureworks

while installing the AdventureWorks2008R2_SR1 which is downloaded from the codeplex site, the instance value is not showing. How to enable the instance there. i can able lo log in to the sql server with the instance HA-INT2. But while installing AdventureWorks2008R2_SR1 it is not showing the instance. 
I attached the screen shot please find it[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just type in the instance name HA-INT2??

Is your sql browser service running? Start it, if its not running. restart the setup...

Comment: We are not able to type there.... if so i can :) It will just show the list of available instances

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.  I resolved this by un-installing the SQL Server 2008 R2 version and re-installing it.